# Updating multiple rows using location cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not too sure how to explain this but here it goes.

I have a database that holds 5 locations in a location table. Lets say `One, two, three, four and five`

What I need to do is update another table `TemplateNames` adding the locationID after the discription (10 rows for each location), however, the location table and the TeamplateNames table are not linked in any way.

The way I have attempted this so far is as follows;

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    LocationID int
)

SELECT LocationID
INTO #Temp
FROM From Location

DECLARE @ID int;

DECLARE Cursor cursor 

FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT LocationID
FROM #Temp

OPEN Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor INTO @Id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

--Insert data?
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor INTO @Id
END

close Cursors;
deallocate  Cursor;
DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

The current description is as follows

```
IAmATemplate
```

But the out put would need to be

`IAmATemplate - one` (The locationID after the name)

Comment: can't really understand what you are trying to do. maybe some sample input/output would help. perhaps edit in 2 locations and edit for 3 rows instead of 10 to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correcctly you don't have to link the tables.It would be a lot easier, if you just multiply the tables then update. I mean;

```
;WITH T AS(
 Select Description,LocationID FROM TemplateNames,Locations
)
Update T SET Description = Description + LocationID
```